# Добавление в бд

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Развернул сайт университета на nodeJS, нужно реализовать добавление группы в бд как это сделать?
Создал представление addGroups.hbs:

```
<div class="container">   
    <form method="POST">
        <label>Название группы</label><br>
        <input name="name" class="field"/><br><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
     </form>
      <a href="/groups"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">К списку с групами</button></a>
</div>
```

Прописал для него маршрут:

```
const {Router} = require('express')
 
const router = Router()
 
// получаем значение из бд 
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('addGroups',{
        title: 'Добавить группу'
    })
});
 
module.exports = router
```

Прописал маршрут в index.js(само приложение) и создал метод для отправки данных, **что в нем не так?**

```
 app.use('/addGroups', addGroupRouter)

  app.post('/addGroups', urlencodedParser, (req, res)=>{   
    if(!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    const nameGroup = req.body.nameGroup;

    Group.query("INSERT INTO groups (group) VALUES (?)",[nameGroup], (err, data)=>{
      if(err) return console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/");
    })
```

Модель бд:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../utils/database')
 
const Group = sequelize.define('groups', {
    id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
    group: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
})
 
module.exports = Group
```

Comment: форма сабмитится в `/`, а роут прописан для `'/addGroups'`

Comment: да...точно, надо action для формы прописать

Comment: Зачем используете raw SQL-query еслиописали модель в Sequelize?

Comment: @Anatoly у меня 2 варианта один строкой, второй: Group.create({ group: nameGroup}).then(()=>{
      res.redirect("/groups"); но проблема была не в том

Comment: Это было попутное наблюдение, а не предложение решения.